How to merge two meshes in python meshlib library
I am trying to merge two meshes in one 3d model. One mesh is the walls and other one is the ground. I want the ground below the walls but when I try to merge them the ground always comes on top of walls
can anyone help me position the ground mesh(mesh1) below the walls mesh(mesh)
from PIL import Image
import meshlib.mrmeshpy as mr

# Load and prepare raster images
Image.open('walls_mask.png').convert('RGBA').save('walls_mask.png')
Image.open('ground.png').convert('RGBA').save('ground.png')

# Load distance maps from images
dm = mr.loadDistanceMapFromImage("walls_mask.png", 0)
dm1 = mr.loadDistanceMapFromImage("ground.png", 0)

# Find the boundary contours between black and white
polyline2 = mr.distanceMapTo2DIsoPolyline(dm, isoValue=127)
polyline21 = mr.distanceMapTo2DIsoPolyline(dm1, isoValue=127)

# Triangulate the contours
mesh = mr.triangulateContours(polyline2.contours2(mr.HolesVertIds()))
mesh1 = mr.triangulateContours(polyline21.contours2(mr.HolesVertIds()))

# Subdivide the meshes to add detail
mr.subdivideMesh(mesh)
mr.subdivideMesh(mesh1)

# Add bases to the planar meshes
mr.addBaseToPlanarMesh(mesh, zOffset=150)
mr.addBaseToPlanarMesh(mesh1, zOffset=10)

# Merge the two meshes
merged_mesh = mr.mergeMeshes([mesh1,mesh])


# Save the merged mesh as an OBJ or STL file
mr.saveMesh(merged_mesh, mr.Path("Merged_mesh.stl"))

